# Is there a way to reference Python projects in VS Code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, python-import

I am working on a bunch of Python 3 scripts that are organized like so:

```
/workspace
  /project_one
    script_a.py
    script_b.py
  /project_two
    script_c.py
```

There are many project folders and every once in a while, one is added, with varying numbers of .py files inside. I want to be able to import each script from each folder in each other script, but since I switched to VS Code, I have no idea how to do that. I tried adding `__init__.py` files in every directory and various syntaxes for the import statements.

From what I've read, this way of importing is not actually supported in Python 3 (which I find weird, isn't it one of the most common use cases of the import system?)--yet it was really easy in Eclipse with PyDev where I could just go into the project options and select "referenced" projects. I was then able to write e.g. `import project_one` in script_c.py and it worked perfectly. I now assume that maybe the absolute paths were stored in some Eclipse project file that way? Does VS Code have such a feature? If not, how would I continue programming without having to use some of the "dirty hacks" I read that maybe enable this?

Comment: You need to install your projects so they can be found by Python when it searches your Python path. i have a similar situation to yours and I run `pip install -e .` in each of the project directories. The `-e` installs in developer mode - links to the source code rather than installing properly. Also, if your working directory is at the workspace level (you are running a script there), you will be able to import project_one and project_two, since when python searches for packages and modules it uses the working directory.

Comment: I don't really want any scripts sitting at the workspace level, I need them neatly sorted in named folders :( So in `/workspace` I tried running `pip install -e project_one` but it tells me the `setup.py` file is missing. Is this how I should use the command? Should I create a setup file in each project folder? Whyyy is this so complex smh

Comment: Python package management is a bit of a delicate balance, but all for good reason (dependencies!)  What PyDev was probably doing was adding the referenced projects into the Python path, which is possible also, but quite a hack in most cases. `import sys
sys.path.append("path/to/Modules")`. Sort of depends why you have separate projects and why they need to reference each other. Treating each as a distinct thing lets you version and dependency control. If they all change in lockstep, why treat them as separate packages at all?

Comment: You can try setting `PYTHONPATH` in a `.env` file in order to have things like the debugger be able to find your files. But as others have said, this worked in PyDev because it was setting `PYTHONPATH` on your behalf behind the scenes and the Python extension for VS Code simply doesn't make those kinds of assumptions on your behalf.

Comment: Thanks, I see. After reading up some more about this issue, I now switched back to Eclipse with a new found appreciation for PyDev...